# One to Many LINQ Query - compiler error

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-5

Please see the LINQ query below:

```
var test = from s in db.Students
           join c in db.Courses on s.courseid equals c.id into d
           where s.name.StartsWith("Bert")
           select new Student { id=s.id,name=s.name, Course = d.Select(x => x.name) };
```

A student links to one courses.  Therefore the value of Course in the above should be a collection of courses.  However, there is a compiler error (System.ArguementNullException).  What am I doing wrong?

I am competent using SQL, however I am new to LINQ.  Please see the SQL from the database below:

[image]

```
***Student Class***
  public partial class Student
    {
        public int id { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> age { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> courseid { get; set; }

        public virtual Course Course { get; set; }
    }

    Course Class

 public partial class Course
    {
        public Course()
        {
            this.Students = new HashSet<Student>();
        }

        public int id { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<Student> Students { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: What does the compiler error say?

Comment: Is it possible that any `name` is null in the db?

Comment: `Student` class where you are projecting your query is the same of your `Student` entity, could you show it?

Comment: Maybe d is null when there is no courses for that student?

Comment: Please show a more complete stack trace and not just the exception type.

Comment: Also specify the ORM used. If EF or EF Core, the exact version.

Comment: @Ivan Stoev, I am using EF 5.  Please see the DDL in the question.

Comment: Try `d.FirstOrDefault().name)`  instead of `Select(x => x.name)`, or maybe `Select(x => x.name).FirstOrDefault()`

Comment: maybe try something like this(havent tested!)
var test = (from s in students
              join c in courses.Where(x => s.name.StartsWith("Bert")) on s.courseid  equals c.id into d
              select new Student { id=s.id,name=s.name, Course = d.Select(x => x.name) };

Also query your database tables and ensure that you dont have null values in both of those courseid and id fields in the database.

Comment: If a student links to many courses you should have a separate database table containing a studentId and courseId rather than storing a single course id in the student table

Comment: @DavidG, the error compile time error is: "Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<int>' to 'int?' C:\OneToManyLINQ\App\App\Controllers\StudentController.cs"

Comment: Can you add the code for the Student and Course classes?

Comment: @David, when I hover above the compile time error it says: Exceptions: System.ArguementNullException, Error: "Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<int>' to 'int?' C:\OneToManyLINQ\App\App\Controllers\StudentControlle‌​r.cs".  I am not morphing the question.

Comment: OP has followed one of the multiple answers now deleted,so now the problem mophed. @w0051977, i guess that error comes because you are trying to set all the results of the query to `Course`. As i've told you, try to add `FirstOrDefault()`  after `d.Select(x => x.id)`

Comment: @bolt19, I have done that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you are just trying to get your query to also retrieve the `Course` navigation property for your students. As such, all you need to do is `Include` it:

```
var students = db.Students
    .Include(s => s.Course)
    .Where(s => s.Name.StartsWith("Bert");
```

Comment: This looks like it includes a course rather than a courseid which is what I want.  How would I create the student and course object returned by the IEnumerable? I have tried:  foreach(Student s in test) { Course c = s.Course; }

Comment: It seems so much simpler in SQL.  Just trying to learn something new.

Comment: Can you explain exactly what output you want? Right now you're not making any sense.

Comment: I want to find the student with name: Bert (there is one student with this name).  I then want to iterate the IEnumerable and construct a Student object and a Course object.  See Bolt19s answer.  He/she is almost there.

Comment: In what way does my answer not do exactly the same thing? There's no need to construct a `Student` object as EF will do that for you.

Comment: your answer has a capital 'N' in Name and is missing a closing bracket at the end.  It is also missing the foreach loop.

Comment: Show me in your question where you ask for a `foreach` loop? And the capital `N` is there because it's good practice C# to name properties like that.

Comment: it is in the comment under Bolt19s answer.  I accept this is not a good question.  I have made lots of changes as I have received lots of feedback and this has caused confusion.

Comment: Well, looping is out of scope for the question. If you can't figure out how to do that, I would suggest a more basic C# tutorial anyway.

Comment: the for loop was not working because the LINQ query was missing: AsEnumerable.  I have written plenty of FOR loops in the past.  +1 for attempting to understand a poor question.

Comment: The `AsEnumerable` in the other answer is a real hack, I wouldn't recommend it. It's likely the reason it got the downvote.

Comment: thanks for that.  How would you approach it? In your comment above you say: "There's no need to construct a Student object as EF will do that for you".  I would be interested to see how you get the student and course object from the IEnumerable.

Comment: `students` is an `IEnumerable<Student>`, so you loop through it like you do any other list. In fact, the same code in the other answer will work.